# How to resolve "The installation or removal of a software package failed"?

Tags: installation, updates

I am unable to update or install or even uninstall things lately.

This is what it shows me...

```
installArchives() failed: Preconfiguring packages ...
Adding user solik to group netdev
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-wicd.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 305977 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-wicd (from .../python-wicd_1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wicd-daemon.
Unpacking wicd-daemon (from .../wicd-daemon_1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wicd-gtk.
Unpacking wicd-gtk (from .../wicd-gtk_1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wicd.
Unpacking wicd (from .../wicd_1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Setting up ushare (1.1a-0ubuntu9) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ushare.config: 26: /etc/ushare.conf: string: not found
dpkg: error processing ushare (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up python-wicd (1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up wicd-daemon (1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) ...
 * Starting Network connection manager wicd
   ...done.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up wicd-gtk (1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up wicd (1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ushare
Error in function: 
Setting up ushare (1.1a-0ubuntu9) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ushare.config: 26: /etc/ushare.conf: string: not found
dpkg: error processing ushare (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: what command did you run to get this error?

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install ushare
```

and/or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ushare
```

---

*broken or not fully installed package*

run:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Tried the 1st one and got this...

Setting up ushare (1.1a-0ubuntu9) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ushare.config: 26: /etc/ushare.conf: string: not found
dpkg: error processing ushare (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ushare
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: and this from the 2nd 


solik@Soliks:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ushare
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ushare is broken or not fully installed
solik@Soliks:~$

Comment: has cleaning your packages worked?